# Unable to get the Azure Cosmos DB using PowerShell

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-powershell

I have been following the article - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-powershell, to work with Azure Cosmos DB using Powershell. However, when I run the below Powershell cmdlet to fetch the Azure Cosmos DB, I am getting an error:

(I am using the Azure Table API)

```
$storageTable = Get-AzureStorageTableTable -resourceGroup $azure_table_resource_group -tableName $azure_table_name -cosmosDbAccount $cosmosDBAccountName
```

Error:

```
Exception calling "LoadFile" with "1" argument(s): "The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from 
HRESULT: 0x80070002)"
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\AzureRmStorageTable\1.0.0.21\AzureRmStorageTableCoreHelper.psm1:160 
char:21
+ ...             [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile((Join-Path $PSScri ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileNotFoundException
```

There has been a question posted regarding the same behavior on Microsoft forums, but it has not been addressed yet:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/0b9c8d20-1bb7-42b9-9889-2ed466badce8/cannot-get-cosmosdb-table-in-powershell?forum=azurecosmosdb

Answer (score 0):

We seem to have had some breaking changes when the Cosmos DB Table API was GA'd, and it broke the PowerShell functions created by one of our cloud architects. We are taking the article down today until we can get the PowerShell fixed. Sorry for any inconvenience this may have caused. We'll have it back up as soon as possible.